# Facebook PHP sdk returns Unknown Method

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-php-sdk

I've accessed the fb->api method several times...but recently downloaded the latest SDK and now I'm getting some weird behavior. Here's the code:

```
 try {
    include("facebooksdk/src/facebook.php");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "$e" . "<br/>";
    die($e);
}
$appId = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
$appsecret= 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appId,
    'secret' => $appsecret,
    'oauth' => 'true'
));
$accesstoken = $fb->getAccessToken();
$me = $fb->getUser();
if(!$me) {
    header("Location:{$fb->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'email,offline_access'))}");
}


**try {
    $result = $fb->api(array('/me', 'GET'));**

    print_r($result);
}
catch(FacebookApiException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

My issue is when I attempt the $result...I get "UNKNOWN METHOD" returned (and occasionally some direction to base_facebook.php). Any ideas on this one? Can't find good data anywhere on the net. 
Are we not able to access by relative_url (I've also tried the relative_url=> method...no luck!). Ultimately I want to get DAU from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just:

```
$fb->api('/me');
```

`GET` is the default method. And when you pass an array, you're telling the Facebook SDK that you're using a REST method, which obviously doesn't exist, so that's why you're getting "Unknown method."

Comment: Thanks Jimmy! Since i have you here: I am ultimately looking to get the application_active_users (and NOT the generic, rounded "FQL" version). Can I pass an array with a relative_url still then? I will ultimately need to pass an array to get the full data that I'm after...

Comment: I don't think you will; passing an array invokes the old REST API, which isn't needed to get insights. You should be able to call `/<PAGE_ID>/insights/application_active_users/<period>`, see [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) for more details. (It actually uses `application_active_users` as an example.)

Comment: Okay...that seems to be working (although now struggling with "no node specified even when logged in...ugh!). Thanks so much for the help!